# How to keep URL parameters on Javascript redirect?

Tags: javascript, url, redirect, parameters

After clicking a dynamic link in an email, my users land on a page with a form pre-populated like this:

http://www.test.com/november_promo/default.html?Name=Test&Email=Test.com

A script runs right at the beginning to re-direct them to a mobile version of the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="redirection_mobile.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
SA.redirection_mobile ({param:"isDefault", mobile_url: "www.test.com/november_promo/default_mobile.html", mobile_prefix : "http://", cookie_hours : "1" });
</script>
```

Is there any way to keep those parameters when they are redirected like that?

I know there are better ways to mobile-redirect with PHP, but my company's server is sketchy about letting my department's directory serve PHP files, so we try to do everything with Javascript.

Answer (score 34):

```
document.location.search
```

can be used to append current location query strings to string in javascript

e.g.

```
<script>
var uri = 'foobar.html';

// while current location is 'baz.html?foo=1&a=b' for example

uri = uri + document.location.search;

// this will output 'foobar.html?foo=1&a=b'    
alert(uri);

</script>
```